# Getting File Path in .NET From Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, io

I would like to get the file path of the application and run a file from codebehind.

In my situation, I have a virtual directory set up with folders like [CSS,Javascript,AJAX,Images,SQLFiles]. In my App_Code folder, I have the .cs files for my codebehind. From those .cs files, I want to read a .sql file in the SQLFiles folder. How can I get the path of my virtual directory from the code behind in order to read the .sql file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Server.MapPath("~/SQLFiles/sqlfile.sql");
```

The `~` here indicates you want the virtual root, and then you're further saying I want to go a little further into `SQLFiles`. This will return you an absolute physical path.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `MapPath()` to get your root directory.

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ApplicationPhysicalPath

```
var path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
```